# def statement creating a new column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my def statement, I am wondering why isn't the created column writing to the dataset?

```
def MA(df, n):  
    MA = pd.Series(pd.rolling_mean(df['Close'], n), name = 'MA_' + str(n))  
    df = df.join(MA)
```

When I call the function

```
MA(df,10)
```

Why isn't the MA column written to "df"

Comment: Because the change is not done by reference. A new dataframe is generated inside the function. You need to return it.

Comment: @Abdou Python objects, with the exception of immutable objects like tuples and primitives, are passed by reference. In fact, I will show you a function that will modify content of `df` without returning.

Comment: @Mai, the first part of your statement is correct, but that is not what is happening here. The user is actually creating a new dataframe inside the function definition. They are resetting `df` with `df.join(MA)`. This creates a new dataframe that needs to be returned. This is different from just adding a column to a dataframe.

Comment: In this case, the change is *NOT* done by reference.

Comment: @Abdou I see what you mean now. That's because `df` inside `MA` function is a different pointer value than `df` outside `MA` function. Even if `df` inside `MA` points to the new dataframe, it does not affect the pointer `df` outside `MA`. It is not copying content of pointed source object to content of pointing target, but simply replacing the local variable that holds a pointer value by another pointer value that references the new dataframe. It is exactly because the change IS done by reference, so it won't work. But yes, it won't work. But no, it's all done by reference.

Answer (score 1):

First, defining the name of variable `MA` exactly the same as function name `MA` is very bad practice.

Second, adding a column to a dataframe can be done by simply

```
df['new_col_name'] = col
```

Indices will automatically align, and unfound indices will have `null` filled in.

---

In response to @Abdou's comment:

```
def assign(df):
    df['test'] = pd.Series(range(4))
```

will add a new column of `'test'` to `df` with four elements. Modify it as needed.

Comment: Good answer . .

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Pandas issue... well not really.
This is about Python and scope.

**What Happened?**

```
def MA(df, n):
    MA = pd.Series(pd.rolling_mean(df['Close'], n), name = 'MA_' + str(n))  
    df = df.join(MA)
```

- @Mai is correct!  Don't ever name a variable the same thing as the function that called it in Python.  I know other languages do this.  Not in Python!  That said, not a big deal, we can change it and we still have to deal with the problem at hand.
- As soon as you assigned the result of the `join` to a name `df`, that `df` became a **NEW** `df` completely inside the scope of the function.  I assume you wanted to augment the `df` outside the scope of the function.

---

**Not Recommended 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.insert` to place a new column into existing dataframe object (aka, in place).  I don't recommend this because I don't like modifying objects outside the scope of the function that is modifying it.

```
def MA(df, n):
    not_MA = df['Close'].rolling(n).mean().rename('MA_{}'.format(n))  
    df.insert(df.shape[1], not_MA.name, not_MA)
```

---

**Not Recommended 2**
See @Mai's answer

---

**What I do propose**
Do what you were doing, but return the result

```
def MA(df, n):
    not_MA = df['Close'].rolling(n).mean().rename('MA_{}'.format(n))  
    return df.join(not_MA)
```

But reassign it in the proper scope

```
df = MA(df, 2)
```